# how to generate Database schema from GWT gilead?

Tags: hibernate, gwt, gilead

I'm using gilead with gwt, and i want to move from my Oracle Db to mySql Db

so i tried to use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property and nothing happened.

Note that I'm using annotated pojo's not hbm.xml.

Comment: another way would be using it directly with `new SchemaExport(configuration).execute()`

Comment: @Firo i tried to change my hibernate.cfg.xml configuration to meet with mysql database, but nothing happened. it just load the previous configuration for oracle database. so can you tell me what the problem will be?

Comment: show the code for configuring the Sessionfactory and double check if the hibernate.cfg.xml is in the right directory

Comment: @Firo it's in the right directory, i try it at another PC and it worked fine.
It seems that there is some files stuck in my PC, and it always load the hibernate.cfg.xml from them.

so is there any way that i can clean my project and compile it again?

Comment: i don't know your environment nor your tools. try google this or ask a question on SO

Comment: I'm using Windows XP, Eclipse, gwt 2.1, gilead.
I tried to google it but i didn't find a solution

Comment: delete the deploy folder and recreate it could help